# Crystal Reports, can it handle Bill Of Material information?

Tags: crystal-reports

So here is what I am trying to do. We would like to create a bill of materials report that will show items exploded into their components. I can do this like so:

Part #1
 - Subreport with related parts

However, here is my issue. Some of the related parts in the subreport can also be exploded into components (multiple levels), so I could have something like this:

```
Part #1
- Part #2 (Part #1 sub part)
 - Part #3 (Part #2 sub part)
```

Can anyone suggest a way for crystal to handle something like this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your data model?

Comment: Crystal Reports doesn't support nested subreports (i.e. subreports within subreports).

Comment: All - I do realize that crystal doesn't support nested subreports, sorry for not making that clear. I am trying to see if there is any other method I could use to accomplish this. Ryan - The data for the report is being pulled from Bill of Materials in a Sage 100 system. So it is using their data files to get the information. If there is a specific question you need to know about it I can find out.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal reports doesn't allow subreport ina subreport one option you have is in a subreport create a group and hide it to get drilldown functionality.